# How do I make and read a packet structure in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, serialization

How may I create and read a packet in VB.NET?
I desire to create an application that sends an object of some sort, and then have the client de-serialize that object, and perhaps establish a 2-way communication where the client sends a piece of info and the server replies with an apt object for it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out **ProtoBuf-Net**.  Fast, small, robust, somewhat easy (sparse docs) and free. **Lots** of info here on SO and [at this link](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).  It will serialize something to a file or mem stream, in less than 10 lines of code (plus some Class/Property attributes) and output something much, MUCH smaller than the NET binary serializer.  The basic code is simple:

```
    Try
        Dim fs As New FileStream(mUserFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

        Serializer.Serialize(fs, _Profiles)

        fs.Close()
        fs.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("PBN Error", MsgTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                 MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
     End Try
```

In this case, a Collection of 5 or 6 ListOf items were serialized (ie nested), but it could have just as easily been a class.  Loading/Deserializing is just as easy.

There might be a way around it which I never found, but when I tried something like what you describe, the NET binary serializer would only deserialize into the same assembly-class-culture type which created it.  This is good for making the output proprietary to your project, very bad for data exchange.  Output was also gigantic (Serialize an empty dictionary in NET results in 3000 bytes while PBN needed 300).  The ONLY place that the NET serializer is a little better suited is when the assembly is obfuscated; MS knows how to get the data and is not sharing with the rest of the class.  Even then, it only adds a few steps to the process.

PBN works with all the collection things like List Of, Dictionary etc but wont natively do things like Rectangles, Point and Size.  It is not hard to write a converter to feed it something that will work (I wrote one for Bitmap yesterday).

The biggest downside to VB developers is that all the docs, examples and talk/help are from/for C#.  That not only makes some VB people's eyes glaze over, but makes it look like it is a C#-specific solution.  Likewise, the info (wire types, packets etc) makes it sound like a network data exchange solution.  In reality, it will work just as well with VB for a variety of situations.